# WordPress - get the 4th post in a query

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress query like this :

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => $tags, 'posts_per_page' => '4' ) ); while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
```

Which gives me the last 4 posts using the $tags. 
But any idea of how may I edit this code to do not get the four first posts but from the 4th?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`WP_Query` Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). It goes into detail on how to properly interact with the class.

If you want to query your posts *starting* from the 4th post, you'll want to take a look at the [`offset` parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). In your case, take a look at the code below *(Note: I moved the arguments array to a variable for clarity)*

```
$recent_args = array(
    'tag'            => $tags,
    'posts_per_page' => 4, // Don't need quotes around integers
    'offset'         => 3, // Add this param to "Skip" this many posts
);

$recent = new WP_Query( $recent_args ); 

// Loop through your posts here
```

Comment: Indeed, offset is the answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all posts beyond the first (newest) posts, you can use the `offset` argument:

```
<?php $next_posts = new WP_Query( array( 
           'tag' => $tags, 
           'offset' => 4, 
      )
 ); 
 while($next_posts->have_posts()) : $next_posts->the_post(); ?>
```

There is a caveat to this! If you need pagination or set `posts_per_page` to `-1`, this will not work. For more information on a more robust solution if you need pagination, checkout the WP documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code gets all of the posts, but that's the correct idea : it's using offset
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code that worked for me :

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query(array( 'tag' => $tags, 'posts_per_page' => '4', 'offset' => '3', )); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
```

Thanks a lot to @disinfor & @Xhynk for leading me to the right direction !

Comment: It looks like Xhynk answered your question, so you should probably mark that as the accepted answer.